# JSON and enabling slashes

Tags: php, mysql, json, jsonp

This my PHP script:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "test", "test") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("myradio") or die("Could not select database");

$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM radio1");

while($obj = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}
echo '{"success":true,"error":"","data":{"schedule":['.json_encode ($arr).']}}';
    ?>
```

The JSON displays well, however, slashes are not escaped, which results in:

It's the weekend

when it should be:
It\'s the weekend

within the JSON.

Also how can I manipulate my PHP/JSON so that depending on callback, it gives this error message:

```
({"success":false,"error":"File does not exist"});
```

It's working well so far, just need to get the finer details right, would appreciate some help!

As for my PHP, I am using PHP 5.4.10 on a MAMP server, if that's of any relevance.

Comment: The code you've provided should escape slash characters just fine. (Half building the JSON as a string is a bit insane, but since it is all static it won't cause an actual problem)

Comment: This is the code I'm inspired by: http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=?&name=Viking+FM and http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=?&name=2+FM (an example of error message), but it's not quite working properly. It displays the code, but I can't quite get the callback to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) article with attention. It describes how you can escape special symbols like '\' by encoding them with different options like JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE in the json_encode function.

Comment: This is the code I'm inspired by: http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=?&name=Viking+FM and http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=?&name=2+FM (an example of error message), but it's not quite working properly. It displays the code, but I can't quite get the callback to work.

Comment: It's working fine on my end (currently). Does the end persist on your end?

Comment: Their code works; but mine doesn't, I'm trying to emulate it on my localhost as a cross-domain, my testing domain is http://www.radio1localhost.co.uk for where I'm doing the callbacks, I also have http://www.radio2localhost.co.uk as well.

Comment: I can't access your localhost through those links XD.
Anyway I would appreciate a little more info on the call back, it must say error when the column (radio) does not exist or when you search the table and it is empty?

Comment: Their code works; but mine doesn't - I'm using the JSON in this script at , I'm trying to emulate it on my localhost as a cross-domain, my testing domain is http://www.radio1localhost.co.uk for where I'm doing the callbacks, I also have http://www.radio2localhost.co.uk as well. Here's the pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/p1YAttt5

Comment: As for the error on callback, this error is given: http://www.radio1localhost.co.uk/schedule.php?callback=?&name= - it just gives the content of the PHP file at the top of this page.

Comment: Like I said, I cannot connect to your localhost XD.
Also I don't see the part where you check if the file exists like the other site does :)

Comment: I don't know how do the part checking for if the file exists like the other site does ;)